# Getting Error on IoT Hub Input to Stream Analytics

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

Over the past few days, we started to get intermittent errors within Azure Stream Analytics:

Could not resolve Event Hub host name.

The ONLY input to SA is the IoT Hub.  The message is related to the the input stream.  We have not altered the IoT Hub, Streaming Analytics processing, or the Message Payload - and we haven't had this error before.

Is anyone have any ideas what is causing the issue?

Comment: What effects of this error? Can your Stream Analytics job continue work?

Answer (score 0):

Todd

```
Yes, we are aware of the intermittent confusing diagnostics, and we have fix in. However, it's just a warning and you can safely ignore. Your job running should not be affected. You will continue notice it until we roll out deployment.
```

Thanks for your patience
Ming.